# I want to know whether the sentence which I am mentioning below is right

Tags: grammaticality

I want to know whether the sentence which I am mentioning below is right

> It's a humble request kindly give a Leaving Certificate of the School.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I believe I can understand what you mean, it's not correct usage.

Try something like, "I would like to request a certificate", but even that is a bit formal. "May I please get a certificate" is probably the most natural sounding.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on why it is not grammatically correct? Welcome to ELL.

Comment: Well, to start with, it appears to be two sentences run together. "It's a humble request" and "Kindly give a Leaving Certificate of the School". Really, though, it's more a problem of usage than of grammar. My interpretation is the original poster is trying to convey a sense of formal courtesy in the request. One could, I suppose,say, " I humbly request that you kindly give me a certificate" which is grammatically fine but stil not something most native speakers of U.S. English would say or even write.

Comment: I'm not the one who needs to know. I meant, try expanding your answer so OP is aware of her mistakes. People on StackExchange like it when you put effort into questions and answers, and they may award you handsomely (in Internet points).

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside style matters as shown in the earlier answer and comments, let's just see whether the original sentence is grammatical.

I think it is a fused compound sentence made of 2 simple sentences.  There are several ways to overcome this:

1. add a comma after 'request' and then a coordinating conjunction.  Of the 7 CC's in the brackets, (for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so), 'so' seems the most appropriate.
2. add a semicolon.
3. add a semicolon followed by a conjunctive adverb and a comma.

I suggest either (1) or (2), as

It's a humble request, so kindly give a Leaving Certificate of the School.

OR

It's a humble request; kindly give a Leaving Certificate of the School.